# How is it possible to repeatedly read from a NamedPipe in Windows?

Tags: winapi, named-pipes

How is it possible to repeatedly read from a NamedPipe in Windows? I get an 109 error, saying it could not open pipe, if I have a ReadFile() function after another ReadFile() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

of course this is possible and need do *after* your pipe is connected and until disconnect. 109 this is `ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE` - you got this error in `ReadFile` when another end is close pipe handle, by call `CloseHandle`. in this case you need call [`DisconnectNamedPipe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365166(v=vs.85).aspx) and then wait for new client by call [`ConnectNamedPipe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365146(v=vs.85).aspx). after connection is complete - you need just call `ReadFile` , in read completion again call `ReadFile` and so on until disconnect - some error returned. if you got error `ERROR_PIPE_NOT_CONNECTED` in `ReadFile` (just or in completion) this mean that remote end call [`DisconnectNamedPipe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365166(v=vs.85).aspx) - your pipe already disconnected, so you can skip call to [`DisconnectNamedPipe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365166(v=vs.85).aspx) and just call [`ConnectNamedPipe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365146(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: The problem is that the client can connect and the server reads correctly from the pipe in the first ReadFile, I checked. But after that, when the client writes another thing in the pipe, the server cannot read from it and I get that error.

Comment: @Ana - this mean some error in your code (client or server). but you got `ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE` when and only when remote pipe close own handle (without call *DisconnectNamedPipe*)

Comment: Thank you, now I understand!

Comment: @Ana - error code exactly explain you what happens. if say you close own pipe handle - you got `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`. if remote end call `DisconnectNamedPipe` - you got `ERROR_PIPE_NOT_CONNECTED`. if asynchronous read is canceled by call `CancelIo[Ex]` you got `ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED` if you incorrect call `ReadFile` you can got `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`. in your case you got `ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE` - this exacly mean that another side **close** own pipe handle before or while you call `ReadFile`. in this case you need call `DisconnectNamedPipe` and wait for new client. or just close pipe