# ReadFile returns 233 reading from a Named-pipe which CreateProcess output is redirected to

Tags: c, windows, winapi, network-programming, named-pipes

I'm trying to run a command using `CreateProcess` and redirect `STDOUT` to a named-pipe created on the same machine(server) which the client is connected to and is going to receive the output data.

Named-Pipe creation on server:

```
    char pipeunc[MAX_PATH];
    SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    
    // Setup DACL for NamedPipe
    InitializeSecurityDescriptor(&sd, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);
    SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(&sd, TRUE, NULL, FALSE);
    SetSecurityDescriptorControl(&sd, SE_DACL_PROTECTED, SE_DACL_PROTECTED);
    sa = { sizeof(sa), &sd, FALSE };

    sprintf(pipeunc, "\\\\.\\pipe\\%s", pipename);

    // Create the named-pipe
    HANDLE pipe = CreateNamedPipeA(
        pipeunc,
        PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND,
        PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE,
        PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        &sa
    );

    if (pipe == NULL) {
        fprintf(fd, "Error: CreateNamedPipeA: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return NULL;
    }
```

`CreateProcess` on server:

```
    HANDLE pipeh;
    STARTUPINFOA sinfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pinfo;
    bool res;

    pipeh = remote::SetupNamedPipe(pipe_name, fd);

    memset(&sinfo, 0, sizeof(sinfo));
    sinfo.cb = sizeof(sinfo);
    sinfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    sinfo.hStdOutput = sinfo.hStdError = pipeh; // Redirect output to named-pipe

    // Wait until client connects.
    ConnectNamedPipe(pipeh, NULL);
    SetHandleInformation(pipeh, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);

    res = CreateProcessA(
        NULL,
        const_cast<LPSTR>(cmd),
        NULL,
        NULL,
        TRUE,
        0,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        &sinfo,
        &pinfo
    );
```

Connect to the named-pipe (client-side):

```
    static HANDLE pipeh;

    // Create a handle to the remote pipe
    pipeh = CreateFileA(
        const_cast<LPCSTR>(PipeName),
        GENERIC_READ,
        FILE_SHARE_READ,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        0,
        NULL
    );
```

`ReadFile`, client-side

```
while(1){
        res = ReadFile(
            pipeh_read, // is the same handle(pipeh)
            buf,
            PIPE_MAX_READ_SIZE,
            NULL,
            NULL
        );
        printf("%s\n", buf);

        if (!res) {
            puts("Process returned.");
#ifdef DEBUG
            printf("ReadFile code: %d\n", GetLastError());
#endif
            return;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Did you lookup error number 233?

Comment: Yes its  ERROR_PIPE_NOT_CONNECTED:  No process is on the other end of the pipe.
And I've checked it out and thought about why this error was raised before I posted this question

Comment: The client is opening the pipe as `pipeh`, but is reading from `pipeh_read` instead. How are the two related? Please a [mcve]. Also, why is `CreateNamedPipe()` using `PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE` instead of `PIPE_TYPE_BYTE`. ALSO, the output and error handling on `ReadFile()` is wrong.

Comment: According to [How is it possible to repeatedly read from a NamedPipe in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43963985/), `ReadFile()` on the client side reports `ERROR_PIPE_NOT_CONNECTED` when the server calls `DisconnectNamedPipe()`

Comment: sorry for not putting details about `pipeh_read`. It is actually just the same `HANDLE`(`pipeh`). The reason I put `PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE` was to receive the the whole data (the message). The data is going to be `ASCII`.And thanks for pointing out the problem with error handling ...

Comment: That needs to go [into the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75908354/edit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pipe server security attributes cannot be inherited. See [Inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/inheritance#inheriting-handles). And you disabled the server pipe to be inherited. According to [SetHandleInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-sethandleinformation),

> To set or clear the associated bit flag in dwFlags, you must set a
> change mask bit flag in dwMask.

To enable inheritance, use

```
BOOL res = SetHandleInformation(hPipe, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT);
```

[image]